# How can show user type name ? like admin, eaditor, super admin etc

Tags: php, wordpress

When users post a blog post, Then show user type name.like he an admin, or user or administrator ? whats type user. How can show this type my WordPress blog post?

Please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get them by calling `get_userdata` with the user ID and there is a resulting `roles` property.

```
$user_data = get_userdata($id_of_user);
$roles = explode( ",",$user_data->roles );
echo  $roles;
```

**Example output**

`Administrator, Editor, Employee`